# Implement Now Playing in Music Player

Tags: android, android-music-player

I am trying to make a music player in android. I have two activities. 
MainActivity: updates the list of songs and displays them. 
PlaySongActivity: implements the basic features: play, pause, next, previous.

Now, I wish to switch between the two activities. When I press back button from the PlaySongActivity, I get back to the MainActivity. But I dont know what to do when I press the NowPlaying button.
Here's what I am doing.

MainActivity.java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    updatePlayList();

    Button nowPlayingBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nowPlayingBtn);
    nowPlayingBtn.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, PlaySongActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView list, View v, int position, long id) {
    intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, PlaySongActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("position",position);
    intent.putExtra("songsList", songs);
    startActivity(intent);  
}
```

Comment: What u have done so far?

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK it is not possible to go to a new `Activity` without an `Intent`. What you can do is use `Fragments` instead of `Activities`. The other option is to use the `Application Context` instead of the `Activity Context` to manage the music and be able to keep reproducing it through `activities`.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what the exact question is.

Please take a look at the Android samples (located in the SDK folder) on how to create a music player (you need a service, and a Notification).

You can't go from Activity A -> to Activity B without an Intent (you can, however go back using the back button from B to A).

**Why don't you want to use Intents?** Intents are the communication mechanism between Activities and Applications in Android, don't try to swim against the current.

To let Activity A know that something happened in Activity B, you can use the Listener/Observer pattern, but in this case, I suppose it would be better to implement your BroadcastReceiver to listen to your Service broadcasts and when the service says: "I'm Playing!" you can do your magic.